# Applying numeric input attribute changes on multiple objects at the same time

Tags: modeling, transforms

I have ten cubes selected. I would like to change their rotation using numeric input, using the edit boxes on the panel that opens when you press N. However, only one cube's parameter is changed.

Same is true for location, scale, location/rotation/scale lock, etc.

Why is the change by the numeric entry not being set on each selected objects? And how to achieve my intended result?

Comment: There is a new way to do this. It works for numbers, booleans and even enum properties. [Watch here what to do!](https://youtu.be/4CJAkvMnfZs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **Transform** in the N panel only reflects the active object. If you want to set the  value to all selected objects, you can also try the following:

1. Select those objects;
2. Setting the value as you want;
3. Keep those objects selected, right click on the value input field, select "Copy to Selected".

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to apply only one value to all the selected objects? For example, only the x rotation and not the y or z?

Comment: @HowToBlend https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/UI#Multi-Selection_Buttons Here is a Multi-Selection Buttons feature newer than this answer. Though it might not meet your needs, it is worthy checking. I cannot find an easy solution for that. :( Maybe devs can. A good way is to answer a new answer to draw more attention. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I might try and bring it up on rightclickselect.com but I'm not sure how much demand there is for it. In the meantime I've got around it by assigning keyframes to the properties I don't want to change, then copy to selected will only apply to those which are not keyed. Except, that has obvious limits.

Comment: @HowToBlend Just talk about if you want to align multiple things frequently: You may want to look at the Animation Nodes addon, I call it "Blender LEGO", because you can create some useful "tools" by playing with it. e.g. For your specific question, [try this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yugEG.gif).

Comment: @HowToBlend Thanks to [Bastien Montagne](https://developer.blender.org/rB177d051126b3ea4a1dec6a016ae67d7f51f233d0), now we have Copy Single to Selected feature in master trunk now, you can try it by downloading the latest [daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/). Bastien certainly deserve our tokens there. :)

Comment: Oh man, that is so awesome. Props to you for mentioning it too! I love this community for exactly this reason. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Blender will only affect the currently selected or the *last* selected object, you cannot mass transform objects like that by default using the transform panel in the *Toolshelf*. If you look in the panel you will see that you are operating only on one object, the one that shows under *Item*.

[image]

However, there are several ways to do this:

1. You can just set the pivot point to *Individual Origins* and you can transform multiple objects at once by selecting them all and using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to rotate, scale or move respectively. Provided the objects all have their centers correct this should work properly. It's not exactly numeric but you can still transform in units by choosing the axes and  typing the precise number after.

   [image]
2. Another way is to use repeat last on the other objects by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> after transforming an object. This only works for one action, the last performed one so make a transform you want on one object, select the other objects *one by one* and run *Repeat Last*.
3. You could also use an [*Array*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array) modifier. You can transform the initial object any way you wish and have the others update and the modifier also has position offsets.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Tested on 3.1:

Press `Alt` before clicking, checking a box, or pressing Enter and this will apply to all selected objects.

[image]

[image]

This doesn't work consistently though if you use `Alt` to [emulate the 3rd mouse button](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/input.html), as `Alt` + click will stupidly try to orbit the camera around the UI element.

If you don't fear [wasting our planet resources](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/youtube-digital-waste-interaction-design), then there are [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWdbrRNCJIA) to explain it too.

Comment: I frequently see this suggested (e.g. "Alt+Enter") but it rarely works for me in 3.x or 4.x. `Copy to Selected` however works well.